# grep: if input file is also the output, then why clearing the input file?

Tags: grep, exit-status

Scenario:

```
$ cat t0.txt
xxx

$ grep xxx t0.txt > t0.txt
grep: t0.txt: input file is also the output

# exit status 2

$ cat t0.txt
<nothing>
```

Question: if input file is also the output AND the exist status is `2` (an error occurred), then why clearing the input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shell redirections happens first; so at first shell empty your output file `t0.txt` then it passes to the `grep` and then `grep` complains input & output are the same; how grep knows they are same(?) because it checks the `inode` number of the input &output file (see the [source code here](https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/grep-src/src/main.c#L1377)/lines 1377~1403).

unfortunately you lost your `t0.txt` content as the result.